# POWERSHELL GET-ADUSER in variables displays an error?

Tags: powershell, getattribute

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding

#************************* Initiate Variable Empty ********************************
$var1="User,expiration date,departament,city,Manager `r`n" 

#*********** Variable $Accounts will query SearchAccount with the Filters below  *****************                        
$accounts = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU=OUUsersguest,OU=OUMex23,DC=ferreronet,DC=com" -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan (New-TimeSpan -Days 15)

#*****Function Query will Initiate "Foreach" in every results and Filter as the Attributes below.****

$Tables = ForEach($account in $accounts) {
    $mgr = (Get-ADUser $account -Properties * ) | Select-Object @{n =" ";e={get-aduser $_.manager | select -ExpandProperty name }}
    $department = (Get-Aduser $account -Properties *).department 
    $city = (Get-Aduser $account -Properties *).city
    $var1 = "{0}{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}`r`n" -f $var1, $account.name, $account.AccountExpirationDate,$department,$city,$mgr
    }
     Write-Output $var1
```

I am getting this as result:
John smith,8/26/2020 12:00:00 AM,SALES,NEW YORK,@{ =Raymond gray}
My doubts is why i am getting the @ {= managername} I just want the display name not the other characters

Comment: Why are you using a variable with comma-delimited content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to create a comma delimites result like this, but instead use `Export-Csv` to create a usable file for you to open in Excel.
In order to do that, have your loop output **objects** with the desired properties instead of a string and capture these objects in a variable.

Also, since you only want a handfull of user attributes, it is wasteful to use `-Properties *`, especially if you do that three times in the loop on the same account, every time just to get one property..

Try

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$searchBase = "OU=OUUsersguest,OU=OUMex23,DC=ferreronet,DC=com"
$accounts = Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -SearchBase $searchBase -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan (New-TimeSpan -Days 15)
$result = foreach($account in $accounts) {
    # get the properties you need from the user account
    $usr = $account | Get-ADUser -Properties Manager, Department, City, AccountExpirationDate
    $mgr = if ($usr.Manager) { (Get-ADUser -Identity $usr.Manager).Name } else { $null }
    # output an object with desired properties
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        User           = $usr.Name
        ExpirationDate = $usr.AccountExpirationDate
        Department     = $usr.Department
        City           = $usr.City
        Manager        = $mgr
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\ExpiringUsers.csv' -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>I added switch `-UseCulture` to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet so the file will use the delimiter character your Excel expects</sup>

Comment: That did the trick I just added it to the rest of the code and works like a charm.
Thank you.